# javafx window switching with button back and forth

Tags: java, javafx

I am having trouble with the fact that I have 2 pane's both in their separate java class and I want a button to open the other one on the page (so go from one pane to the other using a button) but it doesn't really seem to work.
I just started off with coding at my school. any help would be amazing.

Here is the code I'm using on my main class the secondary is called panle2.java if it's needed with a pane name of the pane in my main and root in my secondary.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Pane pane = new HBox(10);
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        Image image = new Image("picachu_pok__mon-logo-D361BD95C6-seeklogo.com.png");
        pane.getChildren().add(new ImageView(image));

        Button button = new Button();
        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            try {
                FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/A.fxml"));
                Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
                Stage stage = new Stage();
                stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
                stage.show();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        primaryStage.setTitle("pokemon stats");
        Scene value = new Scene(pane, 1000, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(value);
        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            value.setRoot(pane);

        });
        ImageView imageView2 = new ImageView(image);
        imageView2.setFitHeight(100);
        imageView2.setFitWidth(100);
        pane.getChildren().add(imageView2);
        pane.getChildren().add(button);

        ImageView imageView3 = new ImageView(image);
        imageView3.setRotate(90);
        pane.getChildren().add(imageView3);


        primaryStage.show();


    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}`
```

Comment: Try to mention and explain the output/error you get when executing your code. "Doesn't seem to work" is a very vague statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems with your code.

1. `Pane pane = new HBox(10);` -> I am guessing this will lead to problems. I tried it in my code and it creates an error with `root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);`. Also, I believe it will cause confusion for someone who has to come back and read the code.
2. You have one `Button`, but you have created two different event handlers for the `Button`.
3. If you are going to try to change the `Scene`, then that second `Scene` needs a `Button` that will allow you to go back to the first `Scene`. (This example does not take this approach.)

In the example below, I don't attempt to change the `Scene`. I just switch the `Nodes` at the `VBox` index zero. This may be a better approach. I am not sure. I also use `setUserData()` to keep track of the `Node` that is currently loaded in the `VBox` index zero.

> Main

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.geometry.Pos;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.control.Label;
    import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    /**
     *
     * @author blj0011
     */
    public class JavaFXApplication269 extends Application
    {

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage)
        {
            VBox root = new VBox();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1000, 600);
            Button btnPaneChanger = new Button("Click Me!");

            Label label = new Label("I am Pane 1!");
            StackPane pane1 = new StackPane(label);
            pane1.setPrefSize(1000, 500);
            root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            root.getChildren().addAll(pane1, btnPaneChanger);//Set the first pane in index zero of the VBox
            btnPaneChanger.setUserData("pane1");//Use setUserData to keep up with which Pane is currently loaded

            btnPaneChanger.setOnAction((event) -> {
                switch (btnPaneChanger.getUserData().toString()) {
                    case "pane1": {
                        try {
                            FXMLLoader listViewLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("pane2.fxml"));
                            StackPane pane2 = ((StackPane) listViewLoader.load());//StackPane is the root node in the FXML
                            root.getChildren().set(0, pane2);
                            btnPaneChanger.setUserData("pane2");
                        }
                        catch (IOException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                    case "pane2":
                        root.getChildren().set(0, pane1);
                        btnPaneChanger.setUserData("pane1");
                        break;
                }

            });

            primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            launch(args);
        }

    }

>Pane 2 Controller

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class Pane2Controller implements Initializable
{

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
    {
        // TODO
    }

}
```

> Pane 2 FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication269.Pane2Controller">
   <children>
      <Label text="This is Pane 2">
         <font>
            <Font size="37.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
</StackPane>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help this helped alot.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems in your code is you are using (1) code to create your elements, and then (2) using fxml for the other pane. If you are using code, just use code. If you are using fxml, just use fxml.

Your initial pane is done in code. One option is: not do the FXML. Create a new class that extends any Pane and do everything in code.

Reloading an already loaded FXML file always gives an error.

If you want to avoid the error in your current code, you have to ensure that the FXML is already loaded. Do not instantiate it on your setOnAction method (button).

```
public class Main extends Application {

    static Parent root1;

    {
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/A.fxml"));
            root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Pane pane = new HBox(10);
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        Image image = new Image("FXML/Capture.PNG");
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root1,500,500));

        Button button = new Button("Winner");
        button.setMinWidth(200);

        button.setOnAction(e-> {
           stage.show();
        });

        primaryStage.setTitle("pokemon stats");
        Scene value = new Scene(pane, 1000, 600);
        primaryStage.setWidth(1000);
        primaryStage.setScene(value);

        ImageView imageView2 = new ImageView(image);
        imageView2.setPreserveRatio(true);
        pane.getChildren().add(imageView2);
        pane.getChildren().add(button);

        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I did not test the code above. But I hope you get the idea.